# Angular REST API Request

Tags: angular

I'm trying to retrieve data from an api using angular.

This is a sample of the data i get when I use Postman(Chrome extension) GET

> [{"cuisine": "Bakery", "borough": "Bronx", "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop", "restaurant_id": "30075445", "grades": [{"date": {"$date": 1393804800000}, "grade": "A", "score": 2}, {"date": {"$date": 1378857600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 6}, {"date": {"$date": 1358985600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 10}, {"date": {"$date": 1322006400000}, "grade": "A", "score": 9}, {"date": {"$date": 1299715200000}, "grade": "B", "score": 14}], "address": {"building": "1007", "street": "Morris Park Ave", "zipcode": "10462", "coord": [-73.856077, 40.848447]}, "_id": {"$oid": "58fffbef0bc7de46499ad5c6"}}]

places.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Place } from './place';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class PlacesService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private baseUrl: 'http://example.com/api'

    getPlaces(): Observable<Place[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
    }

}
```

places.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PlacesService } from './places.service';

import { Place } from './place';

import { AuthService } from '../providers/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'places',
    templateUrl: './places.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./places.component.css']
})

export class PlacesComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        public authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        private placesService: PlacesService
    )
    { }

    places: Place[];

    loadPlaces() {
        this.placesService.getPlaces()
            .subscribe(
            places => this.places = places,
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        console.log(this.loadPlaces());

        this.loadPlaces()
    }

}
```

place.ts

```
export class Place {
    constructor(
        public restaurant_id: number,
        public name: string
    ) { }
}
```

Sorry for the long question but I figured that it would help if I posted everything.

This is error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.Body.json (body.js:24)
at CatchSubscriber.selector (places.service.ts:18)
at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:104)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.js:82)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:367)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:366)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:420)
```

Comment: Try you check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114968/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-in-json-on-position-0-angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: if you trying to use http in angular you  can take a look at repo if describes some of these angular concepts https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts.

a page on gitpages http://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Comment: Thank you. I will check them all.

Comment: I m not sure if I have place.ts configured right. Does it have to reflect the json I get? Or just what I need from it?

Comment: This error seems to be caused by malformed JSON, which cannot be read. You need to check your network tab and see what you are actually receiving :)